# How to update an NSUserDefault

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I have the following code which should update a value in NSUserDefaults:

```
- (id) createBoardWithTitle:(NSString *)pTitle withScores:(NSArray *)pScores andNames:(NSArray *)pNames andDisplayStrings:(NSArray *)pStrings orderBy:(NSString *)pOrder ofType:(NSString *)pType
{

    if((self == [super init]))
    {

        boardEntries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

        // Build the data

            for(...){
               // populate boardEntries
            }


        // create an Dictionary to save
        NSDictionary *savedData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pType, @"type", pOrder, @"order", boardEntries, @"entries", nil];

            // Load the old boards
        NSDictionary *existingBoards = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"BlockDepotLeaderboards"];

            // Create a mutable dictionary to replace the old immutable dictionary
        NSMutableDictionary *newBoards = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[existingBoards count]+1];

            // transfer the old dictionary into the new dictionary
        [newBoards addEntriesFromDictionary:existingBoards];

            // add the new board to the new dictionary
        [newBoards setObject:savedData forKey:pTitle];

            // check to make sure it looks like it should by eye
        NSLog(@"New Boards: %@", newBoards);

            // Replace the old date in NSUserdefaults
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newBoards forKey:@"BlockDepotleaderboards"];
            // Update: Do I really need to call this?
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            // Check to make sure it looks as it should by eye
        NSLog(@" Defaults--- %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"BlockDepotLeaderboards"]);
    }

    return self;

}
```

As far as I can tell, that's the pertinent code. It's probably "wordier" than it needs to be perhaps. But as I understand it, anything returned from NSUserDefaults will be immutable, so I have to recreate it as a Mutable object, add what needs adding then replace the object in NSUserDefaults. And I think what I'm trying above should work.

the output for NSLog(@"New Boards: %@", newBoards) id

```
New Boards: {
    "Marathon: Times" =     {
        entries =         (
                        {
                displayString = "10:00";
                name = "Tom Elders";
                score = 600;
            },
                        {
                displayString = "10:30";
                name = "A.R. Elders";
                score = 630;
            },
                        {
                displayString = "11:00";
                name = "L. Lancaster-Harm";
                score = 660;
            },

            // and so on.....

        );
        order = ASC;
        type = TIMES;
    };
    String = Test;
}
```

"String = test" is just a test entry and is set in the AppDelegate.m file like this:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"BlockDepotLeaderboards"]){

    NSMutableDictionary *leadboardHolder = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Test", @"String", nil];      
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:leadboardHolder forKey:@"BlockDepotLeaderboards"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];



}else{
    NSLog(@"Leaderboards Dict Exists %@", [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]);
}
```

So I know that what I'm after is definitely there. I just know this is going to be something stupid that I'm missing. But I can't see it or figure it out.

Can anyone see what I'm messing up?

Comment: Don't do `objectForKey:@"BlockDepotLeaderboards"`. You have no idea what the returned object will actually be. Use -dictionaryForKey: instead, and handle the case of it being nil by creating a new dictionary.

Comment: if you are accessing the values from NSUserDefaults you should either use dictionForKey: or typecast the object into dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, that's the pertinent code. It's probably "wordier" than it needs to be perhaps. But as I understand it, anything returned from NSUserDefaults will be immutable, so I have to recreate it as a Mutable object, add what needs adding then replace the object in NSUserDefaults.

An easier way is to make a mutableCopy of the immutable dictionary like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newBoards = [[immutableDict mutableCopy] autorelease];
[newBoards setObject:savedData forKey:pTitle];
```

Also, `synchronize` is used to force saving the user defaults to disk. It's only influencing what you see when you open the plist in the Finder. From the perspective of the application `NSUserDefaults` is always up-to-date. Also, the defaults are saved automatically every little while, so the only time you likely ever need to call `synchronize` is when your application terminates.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> A default object must be a property
>   list, that is, an instance of (or for
>   collections a combination of instances
>   of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber,
>   NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

Are you sure about all the objects you are trying to serialise? Take a look at `NSKeyedArchiver`

Also look at this question [Why NSUserDefaults failed to save NSMutableDictionary in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: I'm using NSKeyedArchiver elsewhere for something else. This project in primarily a self teaching project so I want to get this nailed. But I was thinking the same thing; As far as I can tell, I'm trying to save an NSDictionary, with two NSStrings and an NSarray which contains 10 NSDictionaries that contain two NSStrings and 1 NSNUmber. But I'll go back and tripple check it.

Answer (score 0):

At first save anything:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Previous Value" forKey:@"Name"];
```

Then run this code again to update value of the same key:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Updated Value" forKey:@"Name"];
```

> you dont need to call [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
>   synchronize] due to performance issue.call it only it required. iOS
>   manages it well.

You dont need to remove object. Just update the same key. It will update the Value of that particular key. 
Hope this helps.