# How to save an NSMutableArray containing NSMutableArrays of custom objects in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I was able to save an NSMutableArray of custom objects to NSUserDefaults by implementing NSCoding in the custom class. However, now I want to save an NSMutableArray of these arrays. The compiler complains when I try to do this. How can this be done?

Comment: What does the compiler complain about?

Comment: It says "Attempt to insert non-property value."

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: I found my answer over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it. Basically, your transform the array into a data object using NSKeyedArchiver, and that is what you save with NSUserDefaults. Then when you get the data object back, you use NSKeyedUnarchiver to turn it back into an array.

Comment: My problem is: can you turn it back into a Mutable array, add stuff to it then save it back to NSUserDefaults??

Comment: @RafaelMoreira the thing is probably not mutable when you get it, but you can always do `mutableCopy`