# Why is my UILabel not saving/loading with NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Here is my code to save and load.  I did an `NSLog`, and it shows the text which should be saved/loaded but it isn't, and just shows the default text on launch in the `UILabel`.

UPDATE:

Also, in my `NSLog`, it does actually [load the text](http://pastie.org/2675529) but I think the problem is getting it into the label.

To save:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString* CalLabel1Text = CalLabel1.text;
[defaults setObject:CalLabel1Text forKey:@"CalLabel1TextKey"];
NSString* callbltxt1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel1TextKey"];
CalLabel1.text = callbltxt1;
NSLog(@"Saved Cal Label 1: %@", callbltxt1);

NSString* CalLabel2Text = CalLabel2.text;
[defaults setObject:CalLabel2Text forKey:@"CalLabel2TextKey"];
NSString* callbltxt2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel2TextKey"];
CalLabel2.text = callbltxt2;
NSLog(@"Saved Cal Label 2: %@", callbltxt2);

NSString* CalLabel3Text = CalLabel3.text;
[defaults setObject:CalLabel3Text forKey:@"CalLabel3TextKey"];
NSString* callbltxt3 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel3TextKey"];
CalLabel3.text = callbltxt3;
NSLog(@"Saved Cal Label 3: %@", callbltxt3);

NSString* CalLabel4Text = CalLabel4.text;
[defaults setObject:CalLabel4Text forKey:@"CalLabel4TextKey"];
NSString* callbltxt4 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel4TextKey"];
CalLabel4.text = callbltxt4;
NSLog(@"Saved Cal Label 4: %@", callbltxt4);

NSString* CalLabel5Text = CalLabel5.text;
[defaults setObject:CalLabel5Text forKey:@"CalLabel5TextKey"];
NSString* callbltxt5 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel5TextKey"];
CalLabel5.text = callbltxt5;
NSLog(@"Saved Cal Label 5: %@", callbltxt5);

NSString* CalLabel6Text = CalLabel6.text;
[defaults setObject:CalLabel6Text forKey:@"CalLabel6TextKey"];
NSString* callbltxt6 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel6TextKey"];
CalLabel6.text = callbltxt6;
NSLog(@"Saved Cal Label 6: %@", callbltxt6);

[defaults synchronize];
```

To load:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString* CalLabel1Text = CalLabel1.text;
NSString* callbltxt1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel1TextKey"];
CalLabel1.text = callbltxt1;
NSLog(@"Loaded Cal Label 1: %@", callbltxt1);

NSString* CalLabel2Text = CalLabel2.text;
NSString* callbltxt2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel2TextKey"];
CalLabel2.text = callbltxt2;
NSLog(@"Loaded Cal Label 2: %@", callbltxt2);

NSString* CalLabel3Text = CalLabel3.text;
NSString* callbltxt3 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel3TextKey"];
CalLabel1.text = callbltxt3;
NSLog(@"Loaded Cal Label 3: %@", callbltxt3);

NSString* CalLabel4Text = CalLabel4.text;
NSString* callbltxt4 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel4TextKey"];
CalLabel1.text = callbltxt4;
NSLog(@"Loaded Cal Label 4: %@", callbltxt4);

NSString* CalLabel5Text = CalLabel5.text;
NSString* callbltxt5 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel5TextKey"];
CalLabel5.text = callbltxt5;
NSLog(@"Loaded Cal Label 5: %@", callbltxt5);

NSString* CalLabel6Text = CalLabel6.text;
NSString* callbltxt6 = [defaults objectForKey:@"CalLabel6TextKey"];
CalLabel6.text = callbltxt6;
NSLog(@"Loaded Cal Label 6: %@", callbltxt6);

[defaults synchronize];
```

Why is this not working for me? I put the "save" code onto a button action and the "load" code in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: What specifically is not working? What output are you getting?

Comment: Also, what output are you expecting? Limit the example to one of these 6 instances (since all appear to be identical).

Comment: Basically a DatePicker gives a day of the month and puts it into a string (this is all fine, it works perfectly) and then I need to save that into a label, which it does, but when I reload the app - it's just gone back to the default number - which happens to be "28" rather than my specified DatePicker number...

Comment: Also, in my NSLog, it does actually load the text (like so: http://pastie.org/2675529) but I think the problem, is getting it into the label :(

Comment: Might sound ridiculous, can we try like this [CalLabel1 setText:callbltxt1]; and see if that works?

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work unfortunately. I think it's all there, it just needs to be put into that label! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you forgot to wire up the referencing outlets in Interface Builder.

Also, your code has unused variables.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings.bundle file and its Root.plist. There might be some data problem or the objectForKey problem. Check this [link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html)

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: but what would I need to do with this? :)

Comment: Ok Do one thing. First you run the application in simulator. Then go to the settings and then select your application's setting. and edit all the fields there. Then stop the application and run it again. I am sure it will work then.

Comment: No, I'm not using the settings bundle, you misunderstood what my app does. Basically the user chooses a date and then that date is entered into a UILabel (this all works fine) and then it saves and loads using NSUserDefaults - this is what isn't working...

Comment: Ok. So you first take date from user then save it in settings.bundle or somewhere else. coz NSUserDefaults saves in settings.bundle in root.plist file. right?

Comment: Not sure where it saves it, but does that really matter? All I need to do is save and load - it doesn't really matter where it is saved :-)

Comment: ok then this link will help you exactly http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: But my code is correct... I need to know why the code I am using is not working as it's actually very similar to the code on that blog :)

Comment: You need to check the complete procedure of NSUserDefaults. Only writing code doesn't solve the problem. You need to create root.plist file also and save entries there. First check, how to save the data using NSUserDefault. Because everything matters equally.

Comment: You may try this one last option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: But I'm not getting that error? I also don't think that answer will help. I'm sorry but I don't really think you entirely know what the issue is...