# Saving a NSMutableArray using NSUserDefaults not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I have this mutable array named myWallet with its property declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myWallet;
```

This array is being filled up by Cards, which is an object. I create a new instance of a Card from another View Controller so I use a delegate method in able to pass this created card on my initial View Controller which is a Table View Controller. Below is the delegate method

```
- (void)addCardViewController:(AddCardViewController *)sender didCreateCard:(Card *)newCard
{
    // insert a new card

    self.myCard = newCard;
    [self.myWallet addObject:self.myCard];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

So far, I can create new instances of Card, and when I do, a new table cell appears in my initial view controller (Card Wallet VC).

What I want is when the user is done using the app, the created instance(s) of Card he / she previously created still appears on next run time of the app. So I used NSUserDefaults to do this. The method below is how I'm using NSUserDefaults to save.

```
- (void)saveMyWallet
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:self.myWallet forKey:@"myWalletArray"];

    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"I am saved");
}
```

I call this method inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. When I run the app, then create a new instance of a Card, click the table cell, this appears on my log.

```
2012-05-04 14:51:00.900 CardWallet[24998:f803] *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '("<Card: 0x6aa02f0>")' of class '__NSArrayM'.  
Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

What could be a possible reason to this? And can you suggest me ways I can go about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First remove property of your array and then check what values have in your array using nslog that go for key

Answer (score 4):

Your Card class must also conform to the [NSCoding Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) because you can only store `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` and `NSNumber` with `NSUserDefaults`.
That means, you need to add two methods to your class:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)enCoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:enCoder];

    [enCoder encodeObject:instanceVariable forKey:INSTANCEVARIABLE_KEY];

    // Similarly for the other instance variables.
    ....
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

   if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
       self.instanceVariable = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:INSTANCEVARIABLE_KEY];

       // similarly for other instance variables
       ....
   }

   return self;
}
```

Then create a NSData NSKeyedArchiver before storing it to NSUserDefaults.
Like this:

```
 NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSData *yourArrayAsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourArray];
 [ud setObject:sharesAsData forKey:kA_KEY_FOR_USERDEFAULTS];
```

Comment: That is not enough, NSUserDefaults will not automatically encode them for you. You need to do so yourself!

Comment: Question, on my card Class, I have 3 instance variables: name, pin, and points. Given that, does it mean that I should also decode and encode 3 times?

Comment: You then need to have 3 times `encodeObject:forKey:` and 3 times `decodeObjectForKey;` yes. If your variables are not objects (could be a int or float), then use `encodeInt:forKey:` and `decodeIntForKey:`

Comment: Ok. Ahm an error says " No visible @interface for 'NSObject' declare the selector 'encodeWithCoder' " on the line `[super encodeWithCoder:enCoder];`
And I declared the methods inside the Card.h
`- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)enCoder;`
`- (id) initWithCOder: (NSCoder *)aDecoder;`

Comment: Note to go the other way, it's `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
@implementation Card

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)enCoder 
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:enCoder];
    [enCoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"CardName"];
    [enCoder encodeInt:self.pin forKey:@"CardPin"];
    [enCoder encodeDouble:self.points forKey:@"CardPoints"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder 
{
   if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) 
   {
       self.name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"CardName"];
       self.pin = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"CardPin"];
       self.points = [aDecoder decodeDoubleForKey:@"CardPoints"];      
   }
   return self;
}

@end
```

Assumed that name is of type NSString, pin is of type NSInteger and Points is of type Double you can use above code directly in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If the array `self.myWallet` contains objects that aren't property list objects you will need to encode it yourself to `NSData` before saving, and decode when loading.

Check out the answer to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk).

Comment: Thanks! I've gone through this same answer, I've tried it and there still exist an error occurring during run time. I'll try the other suggestion above, where you commented also :)