# Save image in NSUserDefault and get in other ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am saving image in nsuserdefaulf in my first viewcontroller where i am getting image from imagepicker

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)            forKey:@"image"];
```

and i am getting this image in next viewController like this

```
 NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"];
 UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

but when i am passing this image for use it giving me error but when i am using image like this than it works. ( bg.png is saved inside project)

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
```

Whats the problem with my code. ?

Comment: Did you synchronise it ?? if not do it [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: I suggest you to not do using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: than what should i use to store an image from imagepicker and use it in another viewcontroller?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is for persisting *user settings*, not passing transient objects around between pieces of your program. Just use a property on an object that both have a reference to for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zohaib, there is conversion problem in your code.
First convert you image in "NSDATA" and then add to "NSUserDefaults"

> NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image);

then you can get the data back.

Comment: Thanks it works, there were two problems 1) the one you told me to convert image in NSData first. 2) my image size was very big so i had to reduce it size and it works now.

Comment: This answer makes no sense.  UIImageJPEGRepresentation returns an instance of NSData.  The extra call to dataWithData doesn't "convert" the image to NSData any more than UIImageJPEGRepresentation already did.

Comment: @AaronGolden i have used UIImagePNGRepresentation. i have tried with dataWithData but it was not working even i have reduced my image size. but it works when i try dataWithdata.

Answer (score 1):

This method will be called When you pick image from picker

So, take `UIImage *imgGotFromPicker;` declare this in .h file

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {

    imgGotFromPicker = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

When pushing send this image to other viewController.

In Second View Controller:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *imgfromView;  in .h

@synthesize imgfromView = _imgfromView;  in .m
```

Answer (score 1):

To save the image and get it in any other view, you can use this method:

Save by:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Retrieve by:

```
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this image in your app, may be you should to save name of image?
Store :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"bg.png"forKey:@"image"];
```

and after that in  other view use this code

Read

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[myUserDefaults valueForKey: @"image"]];
```

Comment: i dont want to save image i have inside app. i can read it anywhere in my project. i want to save image which i am getting from imagepicker and save it and than use it in another viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You are saving NSData into the NSUserDefaults directly. This is not the right process to do this . You need to use NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver for saving and retrieving data from NSUserDefaults. So please try this:

[NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk)

This link will help you to save and retrieve the data. You also need to implement these 2 methods:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{

}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
 {

  return self;
}
```