# iOS How to save a dictionary of class objects?

Tags: ios, class, core-data, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

Up until now, I've been using `NSUserDefaults` to save my `NSMutableDictionaries`, but now I want to save a dictionary which would look like this: It'll hold different `Car` objects with keys: the model of the car. The `Car` class will have a dictionary of its basic characteristics and a dictionary of `Person` objects (who use the car). Every `Person` class will have personal information as properties. I can do everything else, but not the saving of the first `NSMutableDictionary` which will hold all of that info.(dictionaries must contain only non-property values error) What is an appropriate way to save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an archiver like NSKeyedArchiver to serialise / deserialize your objects to an NSData archive.

All objects in your graph

- Car
- Person
- All properties of these objects not being a value-object
  (i.e not NSString, NSDate, NSArray, NSNumber,...)

must adopt the NSCoding protocol. To do so you use:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
  // Tell the unarchiver how to read your object properties from the archive
  _oneObjectProperty = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"propertyKey"];
  .....
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
  // Tell the archiver how to serialise your object properties
  [coder encodeObject:_oneObjectProperty ForKey:@"propertyKey"];
  ....
}
```

You'll find code example in here:
[Why NSUserDefaults failed to save NSMutableDictionary in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSKeyedArchiver` to save objects and `NSKeyUnarchiver` to retrieve them.