# NSUserDefaults doesn't work

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, save

I am new in programming and i have one problem. I create app, with two views. First is tableviewcontroller and second is view controller. from second view i sending data into my tableview trough perepareForSegue method. My data (Strings) are NSMutableArray and this MutableArray i want to save into UsedDefault after my app didEnterBackgoung in appDelegate.m
Then i want to load it back, but nothing happened. I put my code in appDidBecomeActive in appDelegate.m and i already try write it in my first view viewDidLoad, but no action. My MuttableArray is still empty, after new app start.

here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSUserDefaults*defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.flipsideView.zoznamFunkcii forKey:@"NSMutableArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
}
```

flipsideView is my first View and zoznamFunkcii is my NSMuttable array

and this is my load method:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSUserDefaults*defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.flipsideView.zoznamFunkcii = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults  objectForKey:@"NSMutableArray"]];
}
```

Can anyone help me with that? I don't know why it not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving an empty NSMutableArray to NSUserDefaults. So of course the loaded array will be empty as well.

Here is your saving code with comments:

```
// overwrite zoznamFunkcii with empty array
self.flipsideView.zoznamFunkcii = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSUserDefaults*defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// save this empty array to nsuserdefaults
[defaults setObject:self.flipsideView.zoznamFunkcii forKey:@"NSMutableArray"];
```

---

your saving code should probably look like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSUserDefaults*defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:self.flipsideView.zoznamFunkcii forKey:@"NSMutableArray"];
}
```

and because NSUserDefault does not save mutable objects your restoration code should look like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSUserDefaults*defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.flipsideView.zoznamFunkcii = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"NSMutableArray"]];
}
```

---

and if the objects inside your array are not instances of `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary` you have to encode your array first. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk) for details on how to do that.

Comment: I've changed that code, but still not working. When i start my app is there 0 objects. Don't know what is wrong.

Comment: It seem like i have to encode NSMutableArray strings to NSData and than save them.

Comment: 50 people saw this problem and just one write some help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here you can Save Object With NSUserDefault..

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.flipsideView.zoznamFunkcii] forKey:@"NSMutableArray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

and you make coder and decoder method

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.toolResult = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"obj1"];
        self.toolNotes = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"obj2"];

     }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.toolResult forKey:@"obj1"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.toolNotes forKey:@"obj2"];

}

your Data Save Into NsuserDefault When you Get Data From NsUserDefault then you Use like
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"NSMutableArray"]];
```