# NSMutableDictionary in to NSUserDefaults "Attempt to set a non-property-list object"

Tags: nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying save NSMutableDictionary in to NSUserDefaults. My code:

```
NSDictionary *command = [_otherVC.arrayCommandsAddComandVC objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *commandID = [command objectForKey:@"id"];
[_otherVC.selectedCommands addObject:command];

NSMutableDictionary *commandPush = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:1], @"news",
                                                                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:1], @"articles",
                                                                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:1], @"foto",
                                                                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:1], @"video",
                                                                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:1], @"matchStart",
                                                                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:1], @"scoreChange",
                                                                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:1], @"matchFinished", nil];
[_otherVC.settingsToPush setObject:commandPush forKey:commandID];
```

In other method i write to NSUserDefaults with helpers:

```
defaults_set_object_wo(@"settings/push/settings_to_push", _otherVC.settingsToPush);
```

And i have error:

```
Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
   1 =     {
       articles = 1;
       foto = 1;
       matchFinished = 1;
       matchStart = 1;
       news = 1;
       scoreChange = 1;
       video = 1;
   };
} as an NSUserDefaults value for key settings/push/settings_to_push
```

Comment: Show the definition of `settingsToPush` and `defaults_set_object_wo`

Comment: `SI void defaults_set_object_wo(NSString *key, NSObject *object) {
 [defaults() setObject:object forKey:key];
   }`

Comment: `settingsToPush` is more important as it would appear to be an invalid object - is it a custom class?

Comment: 'settingsToPush' = NSMutableDictionary

Comment: Log the class of the contents of `settingsToPush `, is `commandID` actually an `NSNumber`?

Comment: `commandID` is a `NSString`

Comment: Did you log & verify that, or explicitly code it, or you assumed? Something is wrong in the dictionary and you need to find out what it is - any help I offer currently is a guess based on the information provided...

Comment: check the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk